# how do I run Ubuntu from disk

Tags: installation, boot

I am unable to boot from the disk I burned of the image I downloaded from the Ubuntu website.  I've gone into Setup and rearranged boot sequence and I've looked through disk for executable files.  I found only one, Wubi.exe, but it wants to install.  I only want to run Ubuntu from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the disk in your computer
2. Turn your computer off
3. Turn it on again
4. It should now boot from the disk. You can test-drive Ubuntu without installing it, or install it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the downloaded ISO is OK.  You can verify that by doing an MD5SUM.  Also make sure that you have downloaded the right ISO for your system (32Bit or 64Bit).

Make sure that you set your systems BIOS to boot from CD/DVD.  If you're still having problems, try creating a bootable USB flash drive.  [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) will allow you to create a bootable USB.